# question about the thread balance of multi-thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a program to test the threadsafe_queue.
But the output is like below:

```
    main thread push value 0
     main thread push value 1
     main thread push value 2
     main thread push value 3
     main thread push value 4
     ……
     main thread push value 29
     main thread push value 30thread t2 is created
     main thread push value 31
     main thread push value 32
     main thread push value 33
     main thread push value 34
     main thread push value 35
    thread t2 pop value 0
     main thread push value thread t2 pop value 361
     main thread push value 37
     main thread push value 38
     main thread push value 39
     main thread push value 40
     main thread push value 41
    thread t2 pop value 2
    thread t2 pop value 3
    thread t2 pop value 4
    thread t2 pop value 5
    ……
    thread t2 pop value 11
    thread t2 pop value 12
    thread t2 pop value 13
    thread t2 pop value  main thread push value 42
     main thread push value 43
     main thread push value 44
     main thread push value 45
     main thread push value 46
     main thread push value 47
     main thread push value 48
     main thread push value 49
    14 main thread push value 
    thread t2 pop value 15
    thread t2 pop value 16
    ……
    thread t2 pop value 49
    thread t2 pop value 50
    50
     main thread push value 51
     main thread push value 52
     main thread push value 53
    ……
     main thread push value 97
     main thread push value 98
     main thread push value 99
   thread t2 pop value 51
   thread t2 pop value 52
   thread t2 pop value 53
……
   thread t2 pop value 97
   thread t2 pop value 98
   thread t2 pop value 99
```

As you can see, the time of a thread is almost continuously.
question1: Is this normal? if not, How to make it more Alternating.

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TdLibrary/threadSafeStructure.h"
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    td::threadsafe_queue<int> q1;

    std::thread t2([&](){
        std::cout<<"thread t2 is created"<<std::endl;
        int j = 0;
        int num = 100;
        while(!q1.empty() || num > 0)
        {
            q1.wait_and_pop(j);
            std::cout<<"thread t2 pop value "<<j<<std::endl;
        }
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            q1.push(i);
            std::cout<<" main thread push value "<<i<<std::endl;
        }
    t2.join();
}
```

threadsafe_queue code is below and copy from a book named Cpp_Concurrency_In_Action.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
namespace td{
    void hello();
    template<typename T>
    class threadsafe_queue
    {
    private:
        mutable std::mutex mut;
        std::queue<T> data_queue;
        std::condition_variable data_cond;
    public:
        threadsafe_queue(){}
        threadsafe_queue(threadsafe_queue const& other)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
            data_queue=other.data_queue;
        }
        void push(T new_value)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            data_queue.push(new_value);
            data_cond.notify_one();
        }
        void wait_and_pop(T& value)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            data_cond.wait(lk,[this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
            value=data_queue.front();
            data_queue.pop();
        }
        std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            data_cond.wait(lk,[this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
            std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
            data_queue.pop();
            return res;
        }
        bool try_pop(T& value)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            if(data_queue.empty())
                return false;
            value=data_queue.front();
            data_queue.pop();
            return true;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            if(data_queue.empty())
                return std::shared_ptr<T>();
            std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
            data_queue.pop();
            return res;
        }
        bool empty() const
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            return data_queue.empty();
        }
    };
}//namespace td
```

I just got in touch with multi-thread.
Can you give me some advice, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's entirely up to the operating system how thread execution is scheduled on the CPU.  If you need your threads to behave in a specific sequence, you need to use semaphores and/or mutexes to do this.

Comment: Maybe it is the only way.